# npm github dependency came without files in subdirectories

Tags: angular, github, npm, package.json

I have npm github dependency defined like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "ng2-file-upload": "git+https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload#development",
    }
}
```

And it downloads but doesn't include any files in subdirectories, with the only one exception which is `components/file-upload/readme.md`. The same thing works with direct npm dependency, but I need to use a fork...
Here is the repository I have to include into my project: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

I've tried with npm `prepublish` script without the `npm run flow.clean` command but it has no effects. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

This issue on npm's github: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14420

Comment: This appears to be a bug, as I'm able to reproduce it with another repo (that I'm pretty sure used to work, as I used to use a fork). You might want to raise an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues).